# angular-data bindOne using "controller as" syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-data

How can I bind an angular-data model via [Model.bindOne()](http://angular-data.pseudobry.com/documentation/api/angular-data/DS.sync%20methods_bindOne) to a scope when using `controller as` syntax?

This works if I inject `$scope`:

```
MyModel.bindOne( $scope, 'myModel', myId );  // Works as expected
```

But when using `controller as`, I would almost expect to be able to do the following:

```
MyModel.bindOne( this, 'myModel', myId );  // TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Comment: thanks, so I guess this is the only way: `MyModel.bindOne( $scope, 'myControllerAsVar.myModel', myId );` referencing the `myControllerAsVar` :|

Comment: I have the same problem, have you found any solution to this yet?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, this worked for me. 
Referencing the solution provided by the author of js-data in this [issue](https://github.com/js-data/js-data-angular/issues/323):

```
//using UserCtrl as vm
.controller('UserCtrl', function ($scope, MyModel) {
  MyModel.bindOne($scope, myId, 'vm.myModel');
});
```

myModel is now available in your controller.